# C# WebAPI HelpPage customization - Url Endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having a really simple issue that I cannot figure out how to word in search results so I'm hoping I can find the solution here by explaining.

I'm exploring the Helppage area in ASP.NET WebAPI. Currently I have a new endpoint set that accepts:

```
GET api/status/{id}
```

However when I look at the WebAPI auto generated Helparea documentation it shows this:

```
GET api/status/?id={id}
```

Can you either point me in the right direction to a good resource that explains how to format my xml comments correctly, or explain what I need to do to get the Helparea documentation to generate correctly.

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET so please let me know if I need to clarify anything regarding this and I'll be glad to.

Thanks for all the help and suggestions in advance.

**This is where the endpoint is created**

```
    /// GET: api/status/{id}
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary of my endpoint
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <param name="id">summary of the param</param>
    /// <returns>What it returns</returns>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IHttpActionResult GetStatus(string id)
    {
    //  Doing stuff here
        return Ok();
    }
```

**This is my WebApiConfig.cs**

```
    namespace TestAPI
    {
        public static class WebApiConfig
        {
            public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
                // Web API configuration and services
                // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
                config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
                config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

                // Web API routes
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste your end point method declaration and any attributes on that end point?

Comment: I updated my post. Thanks

Comment: Can I see your WebApiConfig ?

Comment: I updated it again. Also I believe this is the default config that comes with the project template. Thanks - Just to clarify the end point works fine GET api/status/{id} Its the documentation that the Helparea generates that is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've achieved exactly this using this configuration and endpoint:

### TestController.cs

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test/v1")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetStuff(string id)
    {

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

### WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "defaultApiRoutes",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );

}
```

And here's what it looks like on the help page :

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure why mine wasn't working, but it is now. What if I wanted to do something like this:

GET api/order/{orderNumber} 

When I change id to something else it goes back to the old formatting.

Comment: Can you post another question regarding how to formulate end point parameters? I have a solution for it but it should be another question so others can benefit from it

Comment: Yes and no. It says I can only post every 90 minutes so I may have to revisit this later

Comment: Okay. Unfortunately I just got into a meeting. By the time I get out I should be able to answer. Sorry I just don't want to tuck away answers in comments! Appreciate your patience

Comment: Let me know if you still need an answer